# Creating unique user account for a web application

Tags: php, mysql, user-accounts, user-registration

I am developing a web application where I need to create user accounts; the user-id is the e-mail address of the user. User-ids and passwords are stored in a MySQL database.

To create the account, the user goes to a registration page, and enters his/her e-mail address and a password. If the e-mail address is not already in the database, then a new account is created. These are TWO database operations - first to check if the e-mail address is already in the database, and if not, then second to create a new user record with this new e-mail address.

This TWO step process leaves open the possibility that two accounts with same e-mail address could be created. So my question is: How to make this an atomic operation to remove this possibility.

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

**Edit**: Don't understand why this question has been put on hold. Programmers building web applications encounter this problem without fail, the problem is asking for a fail-safe algorithm and deals with common tools PHP & MySQL. Furthermore, an attempted solution has been explained which clearly does not work.

Comment: Based on your explanation. Only one account could ever be created.

Comment: Check the email exists in your db with a simple `select` query and if there is a return then throw an error else `insert`. I don't understand what complication is worrying you?? And for an added measure u can set the email column in db as `unique`

Comment: @zamil, it wouldn't happen by accident, but if someone submitted two requests for the same email at the same time, there'd be two instances of the account-creation code running concurrently, and if the timing is right, they'd both check for a record and find none, then both decide to insert one.

Comment: If two people try to create the account at the same time with the same e-mail address, both would succeed if the two select operations happen before two insert operations.

Comment: *"if someone submitted two requests for the same email at the same time"* - Hm... I find that very unlikely, **unless** it's the same person in 2 different tabs/browsers or 2 people working as a team and hits the submit button at the very same time. If the script is setup properly, and there's a 5-10 sec. time delay, then that won't happen.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it's very unlikely for normal users, but it's exactly the sort of thing an attacker would try.

Comment: You have a point there, especially when using an automated method. Therefore, there would need a hash created and the user would need to verify their email address. @Wyzard

Comment: You'd still need to insert some sort of database record for the account, so that the email-verification process has something to compare against when the user completes the verification step.

Comment: You could use `if($numrows > 0){` in the sign-up page using it in an `MySQLi_` function to check for duplicates. This is but "one" method, there are many ways to do this. This would work in conjunction with `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, that doesn't resolve the timing issue.  Even if there's no record *now*, there could be one three milliseconds later (due to some other, concurrent request) when you try to insert one.

Comment: Sure, but the user will still need to verify his/her email address and won't be inserted until it is verified. Then, if a user tries to sign up again with the same email, then my method works. How would you resolve this? @Wyzard

Comment: @Fred-ii-, user submits two account requests at the same time and creates two records in the table of pending address verifications.  Even if additional checks are done when creating the "real" account record later, this by itself is a potential security flaw.  It's safest to avoid duplicates in the first place, which is why Prasoon asked about doing the check and insert as an atomic operation.

Comment: I understand now. There are certain things I'm not aware of when it comes to potential hack attempts (I will research this). I read your answer below, but for reason (which is not your fault) I can't wrap my head around it. @Wyzard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a unique constraint on that column, to ensure that it'll never have more than one record with the same email address.  If the application tries to insert a duplicate record, the insert query will fail.

Second, you'll probably want to use MySQL's `INSERT IGNORE` to suppress the error when the application attempts to  insert a duplicate record.  Then you can do the two queries in the opposite order:  *first* do the `INSERT IGNORE` to create a record if there wasn't one already, and *then* `SELECT` whatever info you need based on the email address.  If there was already a record for the same email address, the `INSERT IGNORE` will do nothing and the `SELECT` will find that pre-existing record.

Comment: Seems like the way to go. But how does putting UNIQUE constraint on a column impact performance? For example, if there are n records, then inserting a new record should require at least log(n) time. May be it is not important for practical values of n, and because the operation will not happen that often. Just wondering aloud if this is the best way to go?

Comment: Unique constraints are typically implemented with indexes, which are typically implemented with B-trees, so yes, it'll generally take log(n) time to check whether a record already exists.  But that same B-tree index can also be used to *find* the matching record in log(n) time when you do a SELECT, which is much better than the linear time it'd take to loop through all the records.

Answer (score 0):

use UNIQUE in mysql.  That will stop it from happening but you will get an error if you try.  Then in the PHP you'll need something to search the existing. you can do something as simple as this:

SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = 'blah@blah.com';

if the 1 is there then you'd have a user that already exists and you wouldn't wanna try to add that person.